# Changes to volatile variable toggled by interrupt service routine not reflected in main()

Tags: c, interrupt, volatile

I have a real stumper I've been stuck on for a while. I am programming a PIC16F15376 microcontroller Xpress board in C.

I initialize a volatile variable called `buttonIntention` to 0. When the interrupt service routine occurs, `buttonSet(1)` is called, effectively setting `buttonIntention = 1`. [Note: I have also tried just toggling the `buttonIntention` variable directly, with no get or set functions.] In `main()`, the `while(1)` that is constantly polling checks whether the ISR has gone off (which would set `buttonIntention = 1`) and if the ISR did, the `TESTPIN` is set high where I can view it on my o-scope.

I have determined that when I pressed a button, the ISR does indeed fire. `buttonIntention` is then set to 1 within the ISR, because the commented out code at the end of the ISR I tried works fine.

However, my `if(buttonIntention)` in my `while(1)` in `main()` never actually sees buttonIntention set to 1. I thought having this variable as `volatile` would fix this issue because it is shared between the ISR and `main()`, and I thought using a `uint8_t` type on my 8-bit microcontroller would fix any "atomic" issues I have read about but don't really understand... but, there's still something wrong that the if statement never sees a 1.

Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
// CONFIG1
#pragma config FEXTOSC = OFF    // External Oscillator mode selection bits->Oscillator not enabled
#pragma config RSTOSC = HFINT32    // Power-up default value for COSC bits->HFINTOSC with OSCFRQ= 32 MHz and CDIV = 1:1
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF    // Clock Out Enable bit->CLKOUT function is disabled; i/o or oscillator function on OSC2
#pragma config CSWEN = ON    // Clock Switch Enable bit->Writing to NOSC and NDIV is allowed
#pragma config FCMEN = ON    // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit->FSCM timer enabled

// CONFIG2
#pragma config MCLRE = ON    // Master Clear Enable bit->MCLR pin is Master Clear function
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF    // Power-up Timer Enable bit->PWRT disabled
#pragma config LPBOREN = OFF    // Low-Power BOR enable bit->ULPBOR disabled
#pragma config BOREN = ON    // Brown-out reset enable bits->Brown-out Reset Enabled, SBOREN bit is ignored
#pragma config BORV = LO    // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection->Brown-out Reset Voltage (VBOR) set to 1.9V on LF, and 2.45V on F Devices
#pragma config ZCD = ON    // Zero-cross detect disable->Zero-cross detect circuit is disabled at POR.
#pragma config PPS1WAY = ON    // Peripheral Pin Select one-way control->The PPSLOCK bit can be cleared and set only once in software
#pragma config STVREN = ON    // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable bit->Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a reset

// CONFIG3
#pragma config WDTCPS = WDTCPS_31    // WDT Period Select bits->Divider ratio 1:65536; software control of WDTPS
#pragma config WDTE = OFF    // WDT operating mode->WDT Disabled, SWDTEN is ignored
#pragma config WDTCWS = WDTCWS_7    // WDT Window Select bits->window always open (100%); software control; keyed access not required
#pragma config WDTCCS = SC    // WDT input clock selector->Software Control

// CONFIG4
#pragma config WRTC = OFF    // UserNVM self-write protection bits->Write protection off
//#pragma config SCANE = available    // Scanner Enable bit->Scanner module is available for use
#pragma config LVP = ON    // Low Voltage Programming Enable bit->Low Voltage programming enabled. MCLR/Vpp pin function is MCLR.

// CONFIG5
#pragma config CP = OFF    // UserNVM Program memory code protection bit->UserNVM code protection disabled
//#pragma config CPD = OFF    // DataNVM code protection bit->DataNVM code protection disabled

// ==========================================================================
// Import Header Files
// ==========================================================================

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include <math.h>

// ==========================================================================
// Define statements
// ==========================================================================

// Inputs from buttons
#define startButton         PORTCbits.RC4
#define profileButton       PORTCbits.RC5
#define incrementButton     PORTCbits.RC6
#define decrementButton     PORTCbits.RC7

#define TESTPIN LATCbits.LATC0

// ==========================================================================
// Global Variables
// ==========================================================================

// ISR Toggle Variables (MUST be declared volatile)
volatile uint8_t buttonIntention = 0;

// ==========================================================================
// General Configuration
// ==========================================================================

// --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
// Configure Inputs and Outputs
// --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
void config_IO(void) {
    // --- Set output for 5 gate drivers and LCD rs and en: ---
    TRISA = 0; // Set all Port A I/O to output
    LATA = 0; // Set all Port A outputs to LOW/0
    ANSELA = 0; // Turn Port A analog off (Digital only)

    // --- Set output for  LCD data: ---
    TRISB = 0; // Set all Port B I/O to output
    LATB = 0; // Set all Port B outputs to LOW/0
    ANSELB = 0; // Turn Port B analog off (Digital only)

    // --- Set input from buttons: ---
    //TRISC = 0b11111000;  // Set Port C 3-7 to input for the buttons
    TRISC = 0xF8;  // Set Port C 3-7 to input for the buttons
    LATC = 0;  // Set all Port C outputs LOW
    ANSELC = 0;  // Turn Port C analog off (Digital only)
}

// --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
// Configure Change Notification for Button Interrupts
// --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
void config_CN(void){

    //Clear Interrupt flag    
    IOCIF = 0; 
    // Clear all of Port C 0-7 interrupt flags
    IOCCF = 0x00;

    // Enable interrupts on Positive Edge of the buttons RC3-RC7
    IOCCP3 = 1;
    IOCCP4 = 1;
    IOCCP5 = 1;
    IOCCP6 = 1;
    IOCCP7 = 1;        

    IOCIE = 1; //Enable Interrupt
}

// --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
// Configure the oscillator: 
// --- --- --- --- --- --- ---

void config_OSC (void) { 
    // Clear registers
    OSCCON1 = 0x00;
    OSCCON2 = 0x00;
    OSCCON3 = 0x00;

    // OSCCON1:
    // Use High Freq. Internal Oscillator (HFINTOSC @ 1 - 32 MHz)
    //OSCCON1bits.NOSC = 0b110;
    OSCCON1bits.NOSC = 0x6;

    // OSCFRQ: 
    // Configure HFINTOSC to 32 MHz
    // OSCFRQbits.HFFRQ = 0b110;
    OSCFRQbits.HFFRQ = 0x6;    

    // Divide clock by 1
    //OSCCON1bits.NDIV = 0b0000;
    OSCCON1bits.NDIV = 0x0; 
}

// ==========================================================================
// Button Function
// ==========================================================================

void buttonSet(uint8_t setter){
    buttonIntention = setter;
}
uint8_t buttonGet(void){
    return buttonIntention;
}

// ==========================================================================
// Interrupt service routine
// ==========================================================================

void __interrupt() isr(void)
{    
    // If button is pressed...
    if(IOCIF == 1 && buttonIntention == 0) {
        //buttonIntention = 1; // Change state to indicate that button was somehow pressed intentionally or unintentionally
        //OR
        buttonSet(1);     
        IOCIF = 0; //Clear Interrupt flag
    }
//if(buttonIntention){
//TESTPIN = 1;
//}
}

// ========================================================================== 
// Main function
// ==========================================================================

int main(void) {
    WDTCON0bits.SWDTEN = 0x0; // Ensure Watchdog Timer is totally disabled

    // Register 10-1 INTCON
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1; // Enable peripheral interrupt
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1; // Enable global interrupt  

    // --- Call configuration functions: ---    
    config_IO();
    config_OSC();
    config_CN();

    // --- Loop forever: ---
    while (1) {
        if(buttonGet()){
            TESTPIN = 1;              
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this MCU but allow me two shoots in the dark.

It sounds to me strange that you can turn off the W/D with a simple assignment instruction `WDTCON0bits.SWDTEN = 0;`. Maybe the watchdog resets your MCU.

In [spec of PIC16F15376](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/40001866a.pdf) I read on page 155:

> The IOCIF bit is the logical OR of all the IOCAF-IOCEF flags.
>   Therefore, to clear the IOCIF flag, application firmware must clear
>   all of the lower level IOCAF-IOCEF register bits.

I think a simple `IOCIF=0` won't work as expected.

Comment: Interesting point but I think it is neither of those. 
The IOCIF flag must be cleared because after the ISR is called, the program does indeed return to running the while(1) loop forever and ever.
Also, if the watchdog timer reset the program, wouldn't this also halt the functionality?

Comment: That were just two guesses. I read from spec that you cannot clear the generic interrupt flag, you must clear the interrupt flag from the particular interrupt source. Stupid question: Is IOCIF really zero once you wrote 0 on it?

Comment: Your hunch was right. I additionally wrote `IOCCF = 0x00;` before exiting the ISR and my issue was solved. 

It was strange behavior for as it was, it did leave the ISR and return to main with no issues. Yet something about not specifically clearing my port C interrupt flags caused `buttonIntention` to never be seen as a 1 in the if statement...

Comment: Again a shot in the dark: Your interrupt fired again and again because you didn't acknowledged the event and finally there was no time left over for `main()`. However the problem was solved.